# LIMIT by GROUP in SQl (postgresql)

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, sql-order-by

Below is my table students (having 100K+ rows in orignal, showing just a set):

| id | name | class | marks |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Ryan | 5 | 8 |
| 2 | Max | 5 | 7 |
| 3 | Max1 | 5 | 10 |
| 4 | Ryan1 | 6 | 8 |
| 5 | Max2 | 6 | 10 |
| 6 | Ryan2 | 6 | 7 |
| 7 | Ryan3 | 7 | 8 |
| 8 | Max3 | 7 | 10 |
| 9 | Ryan4 | 7 | 7 |

I want to fetch two rows per class ( 5 & 7) having marks <= 10 , also sorted by class, marks ASC

So, the expected result will be:-

| id | name | class | marks |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Ryan | 5 | 8 |
| 3 | Max1 | 5 | 10 |
| 7 | Ryan3 | 7 | 8 |
| 8 | Max3 | 7 | 10 |

To execute below I tried:-

```
SELECT DISTINCT t_out.class, t_top.marks, t_top.name 
FROM students t_out 
  JOIN LATERAL (
    select * 
    from students t_in 
    where t_in.class = t_out.class 
    ORDER BY t_in.id ASC
  ) t_top ON TRUE 
WHERE t_top.marks <= 10 
 AND (t_out.class = 5 OR t_out.class = 7) 
ORDER BY t_top.marks DESC LIMIT 2;
```

> Result on original database:- it's loading since long time
>
> Result on [sample](https://www.mycompiler.io/view/4mF2UC2) :- *Error: near line 20: near "(": syntax error*

[Is 10 the highest marks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68966856/limit-by-group-in-sql-postgresql#comment121886113_68966870)

Comment: The `ORDER BY` in the derived table (sub-query) is pretty much useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use `row_number()`:

```
select s.*
from (select s.*,
             row_number() over (partition by class order by marks desc) as seqnum
      from students s
      where marks < 10 and class in (5, 7)
     ) s
where seqnum <= 2
order by class, marks;
```

Note:  Your question is a little confusing.  You seem to want two rows with the *highest* marks per class ordered in descending order by marks.

EDIT:

Based on your comment:

```
select s.*
from (select s.*,
             row_number() over (partition by class order by marks desc) as seqnum,
             count(*) over (partition by class) as cnt
      from students s
      where marks < 10 
     ) s
where seqnum <= 2 and cnt >= 2
order by class, marks;
```

Comment: Is latrel not faster than window? I'll give try for this on my main table

Comment: There are 99% possibility that in original database 10 marks is not highest and 7 is not lowest. And that's why query will be fetched **DESC** but output should be in *ASC*

Comment: @Slook . . . You would need to test on your data, but appropriate indexes for filtering is probably the key to performance.

Comment: a small query, why we are not using `seqnum = 2` ? As I want to exclude those class where class is having only 1 row (suppose here class 7)

Comment: @Slook . . . Check out the edit.  I didn't realize that was how you wanted to filter the classes.

Comment: I tried to fetch data for all classes, on full main database (200 class having 500+ marks rows in each class, so approx 100K rows in database). This took me 4mins 16 seconds to fetch the data. Very long, was looking to have it fetched in at least 30 seconds. I have created `index on marks`.